# continue to tank in small-town America

Tags: word-meaning

> Republicans ran up the margins in rural Virginia counties, the latest sign that Democrats, as one lawmaker put it, “**continue to tank in small-town America**.”
> Source: [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/06/us/rural-vote-democrats-virginia.html)

Does "tank" here simply mean "fail completely, especially at great financial cost"? If so, my dictionary tells me it is an informal usage.

Comment: ***To tank*** is a familiar informal usage meaning "fail completely", but ***ran up the margins*** looks like domain-specific pollster / political commentator jargon to me. I'm *guessing* it means ***increased the margin by which they won the vote***, but that only makes sense where Republicans won in the *last* election - which implies that ***no actual seats changed sides*** (which may or may not be true; I don't follow the details of such things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it; *tank* in this context means to do very poorly.

It is informal but common in cases of competition like politics and sports. For example "my team completely tanked in the last quarter," means my team did very poorly in the last quarter of the game.

Comment: Thank you. So this echoes what has been said before - "Republicans ran up the margins" (Republicans raised the rate of winning the competition)?

Comment: You're welcome. I would not suggest that they mean "Republicans ran up the margins" in this case, because Republicans might not be doing better. They are saying "Democrats are doing much worse." It might be the Democrats running down their own margins.

Comment: You know?  I mean, I knew that's what "tank" means in that context, and I've heard the word used in that way for as long as I can remember, but now that I really think of it, I can't think of *why* it means that.  Is it just like "Dropped like a tank", since tanks are heavy?  The only other place I've seen "tank" used as a verb is in video games, meaning to draw fire and defend against enemy attacks while doing very little damage on your own (generally to protect your more vulnerable allies).  But that's a more positive usage of the term.

Comment: That's a great question. I cannot definitively answer, but I did find this: https://www.etymonline.com/word/tank. Tank (as in, to lose/fail) is a relatively recent word to the language, might have come from Tennis jargon, and the first recorded use of it was Billie Jean King in an interview for Life Magazine in 1967: "When our men don't feel like trying, they 'tank' [give up]."